# Changing the original collection while looping in vba

Tags: vba, excel

I have a collection like this:

```
Dim BrokerCol as New Collection
'Added some data to the Collection
BrokerCol .Add temp_broker, BROKER_NAME
```

And I am looping through the collection like this:

```
For Each collectionitem In BrokerCol 
 If ((collectionitem.Bid - bid_average) / bid_average) < pThresholdValue Then
     'Want to change something here in BrokerCol instead of Collection Item
 Else
Next collectionitem
```

As said, above I want to change something in the BrokerCol instead of changing the Collection Item. How do I do that?

I tried this:

```
BrokerCol.Item(CollectionItem).Bid = 1
```

It gives me an 'Type Mismatch' Error. Not sure how to solve this.

Comment: What is temp_broker?  an object?  Have you tried just using `collectionitem.bid=1`   It's the same object as is in the collection.

Comment: @TimWilliams can u add ur comment as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried just using

```
collectionitem.bid = 1
```

It's the same object as is in the collection.

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to change in the BrokerCol?  Isn't that a standard vb collection?

Comment: I want to change a value in the original collection instead of CollectionItem.